# ASP.NET dictionary requires a model item of type NO SENSE

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the following error.

> ***The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Vidly.ViewModels.CustomersViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel'.***

Which makes no sense! There is nothing to do with 'Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel', all the thing that I want is just simply passing 'Vidly.ViewModels.CustomersViewModel' in a view.
My code is as follows:

### Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;
using Vidly.ViewModels;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class AnotherCustomersController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: AnotherCustomers
        [Route("anothercustomers/index")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer
                {
                    Id = 1, Name = "sdw",
                    IsSubscribedToNewsLetter = false,
                    MemberShipTypeId = 1,
                    MemberShipType = new MembershipType(),
                    MemberShipName = "TBD"
                },

                new Customer
                {
                    Id = 2, Name = "dws",
                    IsSubscribedToNewsLetter = false,
                    MemberShipTypeId = 2,
                    MemberShipType = new MembershipType(),
                    MemberShipName = "TBD"
                }
            };
            CustomersViewModel ViewModel = new CustomersViewModel
            {
                CustomerList = customers
            };
            return View(ViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

### CustomersViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Vidly.Models;
namespace Vidly.ViewModels
{
    public class CustomersViewModel
    {
        public List<Customer> CustomerList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.CustomersViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customer</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var c in Model.CustomerList)
    {
        <li>@c.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

I pretty much sure the code I shared is right.

I want to return a view(Under Views/AnotherCustomers folder) throught path "/anothercustomers/index".

So the Controller must be [AnotherCustomersController], and the action must be Index().

But I did not get why the view always requires "Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel" which has no relationship with AnotherCustomersController.

Just in case, the following is the code related to "Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel".

### MoviesController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;
using Vidly.ViewModels;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        [Route("movies/released/{year:Regex(\\d{4}):range(1991, 2018)}/{month:Regex(\\d{2}):range(1,12)}")]
        public ActionResult ByReleasedDate(int year, int month)
        {
            return Content(year + "/" + month);
        }

        public ActionResult RandomMovie()
        {
            var movie = new Movie() { Name = "WTF" };
            var customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer { Name = "Stoneway"},
                new Customer { Name = "YourDaddy"}
            };

            var viewModel = new RandomMovieViewModel
            {
                Movie = movie,
                Customers = customers
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

### RandomMovieViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.ViewModels
{
    public class RandomMovieViewModel
    {
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### RandomMovieView

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RandomMovie";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{ 
    var className = Model.Customers.Count > 5 ? "Popular" : null;
}

<h2 class="@className">@Model.Movie.Name</h2>
@if (Model.Customers.Count == 0)
{
    <p>No One has rent this movie before.</p>
}
else
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var c in Model.Customers)
        {
            <li>@c.Name</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: What about the view code?  What does it have as the `@Model`?

Comment: Where is your view stored? You could try specify the location when you do `return View(...`

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the correct view? View is placed at correct folder ?

Comment: In which directory does that view reside?

Comment: share other controller action andview. i don't think so you are using right action/view or shared right code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

This never happened before and I would never know how to fix it before deciding to delete this damn ViewModel.

I do not know when and how I added a model reference

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel
```

in

```
_Layout.cshtml
```

and this why it keeping asking me passing that model in view.

After deleting that useless reference, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: I am also following the same tutorials and I also made the same mistake. Thanks for providing the information.

Answer (score -1):

I am still confusing why it requires another ViewModel.

But, I solved this problem through another unpopular fashion.

I used the ViewData dictionary in Controller instead of passing ViewModel to View.

### Controller(ViewDataDictionary)

```
    CustomersViewModel ViewModel = new CustomersViewModel
    {
        CustomerList = customers
    };

    ViewData["AnotherCustomers"] = ViewModel;

    return View();
```

### View(ViewDataDictionary)

```
@using Vidly.ViewModels
@model Vidly.ViewModels.CustomersViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (var c in ((CustomersViewModel)ViewData["AnotherCustomers"]).CustomerList)
{
    <li>@c.Name</li>
}
</ul>
```

Perfect solved. But a little bit ugly. Or using ViewBag:

### Controller(ViewBag)

```
    CustomersViewModel ViewModel = new CustomersViewModel
    {
        CustomerList = customers
    };

    ViewBag.AnotherCustomers = ViewModel;

    return View();
```

### View(ViewBag)

```
@using Vidly.ViewModels
@model Vidly.ViewModels.CustomersViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (var c in ((CustomersViewModel)ViewBag.AnotherCustomers).CustomerList)
{
    <li>@c.Name</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: So instead of solving the issue, you just shrugged and did something inadvisable and sure to cause maintenance issues in the future?  Good work.

Comment: Thanks for your help first. I do not want to argue with you, but sometimes people need an optional solution to move a time-sensitive project on. Given one or two options does not mean I give this issue up. More solutions are welcome, thanks.